# Ansible playbook vars not working in templates

Tags: ansible

I have problem getting variables work in my templates. Variables work in my playbook but in templates, they are rendered 'as is' without getting replaced by their values. Here is a simple `test-playbook.yml` that I am trying.

```
---
- name: Test playbook vars
  hosts: webservers
  vars:
    hello_var: Hello World
    hello_file_path: /tmp/hello_file.txt
  tasks:
    - name: Copy hello world file
      copy: src=templates/hello_world.txt.j2 dest={{ hello_file_path }}
```

In my `templates/hello_world.txt.j2`, I have the following contents

```
hi  {{ hello_var }}
```

After running the playbook, I have on the host at `/tmp/hello_world.txt` the same content as in my template

```
hi  {{ hello_var }}
```

The variable `hello_file_path` used in the playbook works but the variable `hello_var` used in my template is not working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside the task you using [copy module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) which simply copies the file without any template processing. In order to use template you need to use [template module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html).

```
- name: Copy hello world file
  template: src=templates/hello_world.txt.j2 dest={{ hello_file_path }}
```

Comment: This mistake is so small that it doesn't get caught up early. You think the variables are inaccessible. :P